# Reset Bookstack Credentials

Tags: authentication, passwords, reset

I have successfully installed Bookstack from https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/installation/ and after logging out for an hour and logging back in, it is not allowing me to do so. Reset password option does not work either. I  changed the password as well using MD5 in phpMyAdmin and ensured the email and role was correct. No matter what I can think of I can not log in or get the reset password to work. ANy ideas? Can not find support for this at all and all they have is GitHub https://github.com/BookStackApp/BookStack. Went through the GitHub files and have the mentioned resetpassword.php file uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished via the CLI.
From the CLI, navigate to your web directory (usually something along the lines of /var/www/bookstack) and execute the following command

```
php artisan bookstack:create-admin
```

The prompts will allow you to fill in the data for the new admin user. Logging in with that user, you should be able to reset the password for your original account.

You will not be able to use the same email (and I do not believe that it does any thorough checking of the email, so a phony one should suffice).

From: https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/commands/

Answer (score 1):

after connect book stack to ldap, i can't login with out any user exclude of ldap users, and all of them is a normal user,

create a new admin with command is also not work for me.

then i connect to mariadb and change role_user of my user to `1` and login with ldap password, then i am admin now.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution changing the values inside the ".env" file (usually located at "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bookstack") and updating LDAP server, LDAP base container, LDAP user, etc..